# Find vector's indices that hold elements greater than the elements in another vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose, in Matlab, I have the following vectors:

```
X = [1 2 7 4 5 9 8]
Y = [2 5]
```

I need the set of indices in X that hold elements greater than the elements in Y. For exmple, the required output here would be,

```
Z = [3 4 6 7]
```

I am looking for an efficient way to do this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One straightforward thing that comes to my mind is the following: E=setdiff(X,Y); Z = E(E>min(Y)); But is this efficient?

Comment: I don't think what you're doing it doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Oh .. thanks for pointing that out. Following my previous comment, I think according to my question, Z = find(E>min(Y)). That should return the indices.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that they are greater than **all** elements in Y,

```
   Z = X>max(Y);
```

However, if you mean that they are greater than **at least** one element in Y

```
   Z = X>min(Y);
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I don't want the elements in the second vector to be represented in Z. In my example, (sorry if it isn't very clear), 2 and 5 (elements of Y) are both filtered out. My comment in the first comment generates the result I want. But I am still wondering whether there is anything efficient out there. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @mskb, sorry for not reading your question thoroughly :) I think that your method is already very efficient.